# Is it legal to have one breaker control four rooms?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, code-compliance

I live in a two bedroom apartment in New York City. I have noticed that one breaker controls the lights and outlets in the two bedrooms and the bathroom as well as the hall. Is this even legal?

Comment: What year was the building built? The current Dedicated circuit requirement would not cover older buildings so yes it may be code compliant.

Answer (score 11):

In *new* construction, the bathroom requires a dedicated circuit for receptacles, with two exceptions:

- It can also power lights in the bathroom
- It can power receptacles in multiple bathrooms

In general, lighting can be on the same circuit pretty much everywhere, though it is a good idea to have lighting on at least two different circuits (e.g., alternating rooms) so that if you are working on one lighting circuit you still have some lights available on another circuit.

While receptacles in *new* bathrooms (and kitchens and certain other specific requirements) need to *not* be shared with the general lighting circuits and with receptacles in other rooms, code has changed significantly over the years. [According to this post](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/when-did-bathrooms-start-requiring-dedicated-circuits.2563774/), the requirement started in 1996. So if the apartment is older than 1996 (or actually a little newer, as many places take a few years to adopt each major NEC revision), it is likely code legal to have the circuit as described, because it was legal at the time it was installed and, with very few exceptions, upgrading to meet new NEC requirements is not required except for new circuits or significant renovations.

Comment: A change in occupancy is a big one for updates being required.

Comment: Potentially change of ownership too.  Modernizing the mostly vintage 1950's wiring in my grandfathers home tossed a lot of grit into the process of selling it after he died.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I am pretty sure that is jurisdiction dependent. At least based on the mostly 1950's houses I have seen (including my own) that often still don't have grounded receptacles, GFCI in kitchen and bath, etc.

Comment: Aren't all rewire to modern code requirements jurisdiction based?  In my case, almost the entire suburb was built in a few years as the city sprawled out.  I suspect that wanting to purge all the 2 prong outlets - both for safety and property value reasons - was probably the original reason behind the local govt requiring modernization at time of sale.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight My point is that it isn't just *what* the requirements are (each jurisdiction adopting a particular NEC version at a different time, many with local amendments) but that the concept of requiring rewire to modern requirements in and of itself is a jurisdiction specific thing. 2-prong receptacles are actually, IMHO, less of a concern (though I have been upgrading mine) than lack of GFCI in kitchen & bath.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight How on earth is your local gov't not voted out of office after that (and a new gov't that will repeal that voted in)? I'm not saying it's not a good idea, just that it would be really bitter medicine for people to swallow.

Comment: @user3067860 Agreed. In my area, you even see (especially when the market is hot) "as is" sales where you *expect* to see old wiring, plumbing and who knows what else wrong with it. The new owner can then decide what/how much to fix/update/renovate depending on their needs and their balance of cost vs. improved safety.

Comment: @user3067860 not my local govt; but my guess is it was sold to voters as "homes with only 2 prong outlets are unappealing to buyers, and their lower sale prices make the community less attractive dragging down the value of everyone's home".  (GFCI might be more important safety wise, but not being able to plug things in is something even the clueless will recognize as a problem.)  Also, the only people being impacted are buyers (who can't vote) and sellers (who soon won't be able to vote), so I suspect most people didn't have a big problem with it because it didn't impact them immediately.

Comment: Ironically, @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, almost nothing uses three-prong plugs any more and the things that do are usually major appliances.   Forcing sellers to upgrade all the outlets in a house when most of them will only ever be used for phone chargers is a massively foolish waste of community resources.

Comment: @jay613 I would definitely *not* say "almost nothing". Plenty of computers, monitors, printers do. And some small kitchen appliances - but kitchens (because of GFCI) are more likely to have 3-prong receptacles when the rest of the house doesn't, so that's not as much of an issue. Many vacuum cleaners. refrigerators, etc. I have upgraded my receptacles one at a time as I have either had a real need or just to provide more flexibility (plug in the computer "here" or "there" instead of just "there"). (And actually found/fixed some of the previous owner's mistakes in the process...)

Comment: Sure, but the point remains that upgrading outlets where needed is a better use of resources and if a town wants to force $X of improvements out of every sale transaction, whether for safety, perceived value, or whatever .... there are better ways to do it than swapping out all the outlets in every house.  In fact, that might prevent buyers from investing in more impactful improvements.

Comment: @jay613 100% agreed with the last comment. Plus forcing *specifically* 2-prong -> 3-prong will unfortunately lead some people to cheat ("why do I need this...waste of money...I won't benefit anyway since I'm selling the house and will never use it...connects neutral to ground on any receptacle that doesn't have an available ground wire or metal conduit...makes things *less* safe instead of safer).

Comment: The upgrading work that was done needed to pass inspection (presumably a permit was needed).  I wasn't directly involved, and don't know if they required a pre-sale inspection or if the seller was allowed to self-certify. Only that it didn't come up until relatively close to the original closing date; and that getting the work done and signed off on delayed it by at least a few weeks.

Comment: **pass inspection** It is generally considered advisable for a buyer to have a *home inspector* take a look at the entire house before finalizing a contract. Often (but not always) there will be a contingency clause in the contract allowing the buyer to back out if the inspector finds problems and the seller doesn't agree to fix those problems. However, most things that a home inspector (this is **not** a city/county/state building or electrical inspector, it is a private company) are not *the house will burn down* problems but recommendations for good improvements. A home inspector will

Comment: typically inspect roof (looking for evidence of leaks, estimate remaining lifetime), plumbing (does it all work, evidence of leaks, items not to code), electrical (does it all work, evidence of problems such as arcing, items not to code), general structural condition, appliances basically functioning, etc. When it comes to electrical in particular, they are not (usually - some may be) licensed electricians and they are **not** "code inspectors". So, for example, they may write up "2-prong receptacles should be replaced with properly grounded 3-prong receptacles" and "GFCI required in kitchen

Comment: and bathroom" and "hot/neutral reversed in receptacles x, y, and x". All of those are things that *ideally* should be fixed. But if the house was built (and circuits installed) prior to *code requirements* for 3-prong receptacles and GFCI, then those first two items are points for negotiation but *not* absolute requirements for sale. Even the last one - an actual code violation (which, in my house, apparently the home inspector 30 years ago missed! Probably because he only checked some receptacles, not every single one, which is typical.) is not, in most places, *required by law* to be fixed.

Comment: The buyer then takes the report of the home inspector and goes back to the seller (usually via the real estate agent) and lists the items they want fixed. If the seller chooses (slow market or the offer from the buyer is high enough or this offer is "better" than other offers in some way) they may say "Ok, this will all cost me a couple thousand but easier to do it all and be done". Or may say "I'll fix the real violations but not the grandfathered items". Or may say "Sorry, as-is. If you don't like it then contract void because I've got 3 other offers waiting." Or may say "I'll give you

Comment: $3,000 credit at closing to cover this, but you deal with an electrician yourself because I don't want to bother". Or anything in between. And the buyer can respond in the way they feel fit. The buyer may not even care about most of the stuff the inspector finds, but the inspector is cheap insurance against surprises (but not a 100% guarantee of that either). **TL;DR What you thought was government (over)regulation may have been a private home inspector and the buyer making the case for modernizing the electrical system even when not required by law.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, hall outlets/lights, 2 bedroom outlets/lights, and bathroom hardwired loads (lights etc) can be all on the same circuit.

There is no requirement of "1 circuit per bedroom" since bedroom outlets were conceived of *for lighting*, and nobody ever imagined an air conditioner in every room.  Anyway modern small 5000 BTU **window** A/C's pull less than 5 amps, so no trouble running 2 of those on a circuit.  If you can't run two window A/C's, you're either too ambitious (trying to run big units) or are running old inefficient units, or "portable" A/Cs which are also dreadfully inefficient [for different reasons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc).

A special rule applies to bathroom *receptacles*.  They must be on a dedicated 20A circuit that serves only receptacles in bathrooms plural, or (alternate rule) only receptacles and hardwired loads in one bathroom. That's for hair dryers etc.

NEC says the following:

> 90.1(A) Practical Safeguarding. The purpose of this Code is the practical safeguarding of persons and property from hazards arising from the use of electricity. **This Code is not intended as a design specification** or an instruction manual for untrained persons.

Many people including landlords and builders mistake NEC for a "Best practices for world-class homes" design guide. Actually, it's "Slumlord Bare Minimums *below which, a home is not fit for human habitation*".

Unfortunately, the bathroom requirement was added to Code in the, gosh, 1990s? And any work that was issued a permit prior to that is allowed to remain the way it is.  My entire cottage runs on 2 breakers. We know our amp loads and don't exceed our breaker rating.  Want to run the toaster (8), turn the heater (12 or 7) to "low".